# Do I need to save Isabelle files to import them?

Tags: list, sum, isabelle

I want to import the ListSum theory which, in turn, depends on the ListAux, EfficientNat, and Main theory files.

However, I was unable to import these so I tried copying and saving ListSum but it depends on ListAux and that seems to use an outdated style/syntax (at least the version I found on google).

In the end, I just want to do something like

n = \sum_{i =1..m} (List!i)*i

First, what files do I actually need to sum over a list and do I need to save them locally?  I successfully imported the HOL.Groups_List and HOL.Factorial (theories?) without needing to download these locally... why?  But when I try to add ListSum to the "imports" line it throws an error.

Secondly, how do I write the above summation in Isabelle?

Comment: In Isabelle, your summation is written as `∑i ∈ {1..m}. List ! i * i`. You don't need to import anything special for this.

Comment: @JavierDíaz thank you! Such an obvious answer.  But then what is the ListSum file used for then?

Comment: The `ListSum` theory is part of the entry _Flyspeck I: Tame Graphs_ in the Isabelle AFP (see https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Flyspeck-Tame.html) and seems to be an internal theory which basically contains the special syntax `∑⇘x∈xs⇙ f` for summation over lists plus associated properties.

Comment: I will turn my comments above into a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListSum` theory is part of the entry *Flyspeck I: Tame Graphs* in the Isabelle AFP (see [isa-afp.org/entries/Flyspeck-Tame.html](https://isa-afp.org/entries/Flyspeck-Tame.html)) and seems to be an internal theory which basically contains the special construct `∑⇘x ∈ xs⇙ f` for summation over lists plus associated properties.

Regarding the second part of your question: In Isabelle, your summation is written as `∑i ∈ {1..m}. List ! i * i`. You don't need to import anything special for this.

Comment: Through much experimentation I discovered you do, in fact, have to save files locally which was the real heart of my question; but I appreciate your input.